# Nested routes without resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have an application with an object, movies, that doesn't use some of the standard RESTful routes. I don't want the 'new' route to lead anywhere.

The problem is I have 'movies' with a nested resource 'reviews'

```
 resources :movies do 
   resources :reviews 
 end
```

I want this style of routing:

```
get '/movies', to: "movies#index"
```

But with nested routes. Is this possible? I'm sure there's answer to this somewhere on this site, but I can't find it.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to limit the movies routes? I don't understand what you mean by, "I want this style of routing".

Comment: Yes. I want to limit the routes while maintaining the nesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
resources :movies, :only => [:index] do 
  resources :reviews 
end
```

Which will give you:

```
     movie_reviews GET    /movies/:movie_id/reviews(.:format)             reviews#index
                   POST   /movies/:movie_id/reviews(.:format)             reviews#create
  new_movie_review GET    /movies/:movie_id/reviews/new(.:format)         reviews#new
 edit_movie_review GET    /movies/:movie_id/reviews/:id/edit(.:format)    reviews#edit
      movie_review GET    /movies/:movie_id/reviews/:id(.:format)         reviews#show
                   PATCH  /movies/:movie_id/reviews/:id(.:format)         reviews#update
                   PUT    /movies/:movie_id/reviews/:id(.:format)         reviews#update
                   DELETE /movies/:movie_id/reviews/:id(.:format)         reviews#destroy
            movies GET    /movies(.:format)                               movies#index
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I appreciate the help.

Comment: Any suggestion if I want to use alias for the routes with `as:` ?

Comment: Hi, there, @hackvan. Feel free to post a question with some detail and I'll be happy to take a look. Good luck!